# Why does imported file produce one more repeated result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a file to import, let's say pizza.py.

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings): 
    """Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
    print("\nMaking a " + str(size) +
          "-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra cheese')
```

and I called the module in this program, let's say making_pizza.py

```
import pizza

pizza.make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
pizza.make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra cheese')
```

Are there any setting that I made that produce one more repeated result?

Below is the one more repeated result.

```
Making a 16-inch pizza with the following toppings:
- pepperoni

Making a 12-inch pizza with the following toppings:
- mushrooms
- green peppers
- extra cheese

Making a 16-inch pizza with the following toppings:
- pepperoni

Making a 12-inch pizza with the following toppings:
- mushrooms
- green peppers
- extra cheese
```

So from these two scripts, what made the result to produce one more repeated return?

Comment: You need `if __name__ == "__main__"`  in the script you're importing. Your script is being executed on import and then again when you actually call the function. Anything under that shield will not be executed on import.

Comment: You're calling the function inside the module, and you're calling it outside the module. What did you expect this to do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include all the code inside main block to avoid executing it during import as below:

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings): 
    """Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
    print("\nMaking a " + str(size) +
          "-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')  # this line will execute during import because it is not within main block
if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra cheese')  # this line is under main block hence it will only execute when you execute this file not on import
```